# Fail Data With Excel (Float)

Tags: java

I generated Excel with Data from BD, All is correct a except the type float.

In my BD I have "3.2" but in my Excell I have -> 3,20000004768372

```
    try {

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(eyelash);
        XSSFDataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("Text")); //I need type text for others inputs in my Excel
        styleRow.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("Text"));
        String[] header = {"width"};
        XSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
        XSSFCell cell;

            int myRowData = 1;
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) myRowData);

            List<MyClass> list = this.select();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(list.get(i).getWidth()); 
                myRowData++;
                row = sheet.createRow((short) myRowData);

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

CLASS JAVA->

```
public class MyClass{

 private float width;

 public MyClass(){}

 public MyClass(float width){
   width=width;
 }

public void setWidth(float width) {
    this.width= width;
}


public Float getWidth() {
    return width;
}
```

}

I can't use round because else never know width real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the precision of the values is a problem you should look at the difference between `floats` and `doubles`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net) and [here](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html)

Comment: No,no In my BD I only insert "Float"  3,2 for example, but when I build excel I get 3,2000000000000004626267272

Comment: You can specify 3.2 but the floating point math will still add extra 'digits' to the end. Try it with doubles or a more precise data type, instead.

Comment: How do I do it so that it does not happen?

Comment: You can have a look at [these](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) data types, generally double would be better for the purpose of your requirements but... if you were to be using this for financial purposes using ints/bigints/longs etc, and cents vs decimals and dollars is generally a better approach.

Comment: Thanks I used Double. =)

Comment: @EduBw If that fixed your issue could you accept/vote this answer to close the question?